# Prevent ANGULAR pages from rendering if NODE proxy is not running

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, proxy

I have a node proxy and angular in the front end.
Is there a way that I can always redirect to an angular page of (server down! sorry! ) if the node proxy is not running? I do not want to allow people to see the other more secure pages without the node proxy up.

I was thinking of using HTTP status, but is there some simple way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$http` interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) can do that for you in a global way

With the interceptors, you can look at each request's response.  I would suggest using HTTP status, particularly 503 "Service Unavailable" (The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance). Generally, this is a temporary state.)

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($location) {
  var handleResponse = function(response) {
     if(response.status === 503){
        $location.path('/503.html'); // not sure if you are using ui-router or how your routing is set up...
     }else{
        return response;
     }
  };
  return {
    'response': handleResponse,
    'responseError': handleResponse,
  };
});
```

Comment: Cool! It seems from the documentation that it has to exist in a service.
could this work in the .run() function in the app.module?

Comment: since I'm using stateProvider, should I have the intercepter surround all my states so that it checks at each state?
for ex) 
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($location) {
  var handleResponse = function(response) {
     stateprovider.state()
  };
  return {
    'response': handleResponse,
    'responseError': handleResponse,
  };
});

Comment: You can inject `$state` right next to `$location` then you can do `$state.go(...)`. `stateProvider` is for setting up the states, `$state.go()` is to transition to a state.

Comment: kind of a different question than the posted question.
Now with the intercepter, it seems to occur after the angular page begins to render.
Thus, i get this flash of the secured page before it reroutes to the state I want it at
got any hints/ideas to make this seamless?

Comment: Hiya!
I ended up fixing it :) Thanks!